# For $A \subset \Bbb{R}^n$, show $A^{\circ} =\left(\overline{(A^c)}\right)^c$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ . Show that $$A^{\circ} =\left(\overline{(A^c)}\right)^c$$

Comment: Hi Juan. What have you tried, what are your thoughts about it? At the moment your post shows no evidence of effort. You can click "Edit" above, to improve your post. You should also review the following, since you are new here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Comment: Note that $A^\circ, \partial A, (A^c)^\circ$ forms a partition of the space. Then $\overline{(A^c)} = \partial A \cup (A^c)^\circ$ from which it follows that $\overline{(A^c)}^c = A^\circ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to prove equality of sets.
This is done by showing $A^\circ \subseteq (\overline{A^c})^c$ and

$A^\circ \supseteq (\overline{A^c})^c$.

First we notice that $(\overline{A^c})^c$ is open. (Why?)

Therefor to prove that $(\overline{A^c})^c\subseteq A^\circ$, it is enough to show that $(\overline{A^c})^c\subseteq A$. (Why?)

This is easy to see. (How?)

For the other inclusion $A^\circ \subseteq (\overline{A^c})^c$:

Let $x\in A^\circ$. We have to prove that $x\in(\overline{A^c})^c$.

This boils down to showing that $x\notin \overline{X-A}$. (Why?)

Assume $x\in\overline{X-A}$. This is equivalent to the statement that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ we have that $(X-A)\cap U\neq\emptyset$. (Eventually proof this result first, this is not so difficult.). But this is a contradiction. Which neighborhood of $x$ do we use?